# Whenever I insert data into the database, I get to see blank spaces where the data needs to be

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a question about this topic. The thing is as follows, I am currently a beginner in Object Oriented PHP programming and I came across a problem when I was coding. When I started to INSERT INTO 'dB name' it worked. But the problem is whenever I go to PHPmyAdmin I see blank spaces where my data should be.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);



class DBinject{


 public $naamroute;
 public $soortroute;
 public $tijdsduur;
 public $lengteroute;


public function setroutename($routename){
    if(!is_string($routename) || empty($routename)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->naamroute = $routename;
}
public function setroute($route){
    if(!is_string($route) || empty($route)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->soortroute = $route;
}
public function settimelength($timelength){
      if(!is_string($timelength) || empty($timelength)){
          return false;
    }
    $this->tijdsduur = $timelength;
}
public function setroutelength($routelength){
    if(!is_string($routelength) || empty($routelength)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->routelengte = $routelength;
} 

public function Opslaan(){ 

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "fietsroutes");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo"Connected succesfully.";
    }


    $query = "INSERT INTO fietsroutes (naamroute, soortroute, tijdsduur, lengteroute)
    VALUES('$this->naamroute', '$this->soortroute', '$this->tijdsduur', '$this->lengteroute')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    return $result;
    }
}



 $conn = new DBinject();

    $conn->setnaamroute($_POST['routename']); 
    $conn->setsoortroute($_POST['route']); 
    $conn->settijdsduur($_POST['timelength']);
    $conn->setlengteroute($_POST['routelength']);

 $conn->Opslaan();

?>
```

bump

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually giving your variables `('$this->naamroute', '$this->soortroute', '$this->tijdsduur', '$this->lengteroute')` any values in the code that you've provided, so you are in fact putting empty values into the database.

Comment: I have another 'PHP' file that contains of HTML and a form action POST, so that's where i give up the data. And in this file i collect the data and post it in the database. But that's the problem haha thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @Kayelder you are passing the POST variables correctly, but not using them in your query. You never modify the properties of your class. Your 'setter' methods are defining variables that are local to only that method, and assigning the POST data to these. When that method finishes execution, the variable is gone. I would suggest that you change your setter functions to match this style:

`public function setnaamroute($routename){
    if(!is_string($routename) || empty($routename)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->naamroute = $routename;
}`

Comment: One additional thing, it's generally considered good practice to set your class properties (the variables you have define at the top of your class) to either `private` or `protected`. This means that they can only be accessed/modified within that class, or that class and it's children respectively.

This is not affecting your query currently though. Just something noteworthy to look into learning :)

Comment: Ah i see what you did here. You basically switched my naamroute with routename. So that the filled SQL query i have actually injects data into my Database Edit: Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Kayelder yes. When using a method to set class properties, the syntax is always:

`public function method_name($value_to_save) {
    $this->property_to_modify = $value_to_save;
}`

Do you see how that works?

Comment: Ouch. There is an error here. I did the public function setnaamroute($routename){ if(!is_string($routename) || empty($routename)){ return false; } $this->naamroute = $routename; } you just posted. But yeah that gives me an error :\

Comment: Yeah i see how it works. That's why i also created a function called Opslaan() 'means save'

Comment: BTW: sorry if i sound like a complete moron i'm an absolute amateur in this

Comment: @Kayelder would you care to post the error that you're getting? Maybe include this new code and the error in your original question too.

Don't apologise; we all start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Your table-name and database-name both are same? as you said in question you are firing the "INSERT INTO 'dB name'" so try INSERT INTO 'table-name' i think this is the problem..